# Help with using an array to insert items into a textbox vb.net

Tags: vb.net, arrays, textbox, listbox

I'm still a student without much experience using vb.net and I am having some trouble splitting a string within an array into 2 values.  For example in my textbox I have several lines of measurements that are Length x Width: 20x14, 10x8, 16x13. Each measurement is on its own line.  I'm trying to split all Width values that are greater than 12 into 2 separate measurements, so with that last example, I would have 5 measurements (LxW): 20x12, 20x2, 10x8, 16x12, 16x1, then I would like to add these measurements to a new textbox with each measurement on its own line.

Here is the code I have so far. Again, I am very new to programming and this is the first serious project for me since "Hello World", so what I have might be way off.  Thanks in advance.

```
    Dim room As String = RoomsTextBox.Text
    If room.EndsWith(vbCrLf) Then room = room.Substring(0, room.Length - vbCrLf.Length)
    Dim roomarray() As String = room.Split(vbCrLf)
    Dim Cuts(roomarray.Length - 1, 0) As String
    RoomsTextBox.Select(0, 0)

    Dim CutLength As Integer
    Dim CutWidth As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    CutsTextBox.Select()

    Cuts(i, j) = (Val(roomarray(i).Split("x")(0))) & Val(roomarray(j).Split("x")(1))
    For i = 0 To Cuts.GetUpperBound(0)
        For j = 0 To Cuts.GetUpperBound(1)
            Cuts(i, j) = 0
        Next
        If Val(roomarray(i)) > 12 Then
            CutWidth = Val(roomarray(i)) - 12
            CutLength = Val(roomarray(j))

        Else
            CutWidth = Val(roomarray(i))
            CutLength = Val(roomarray(j))
        End If
        Dim inserttext = CutsTextBox.Text
        Dim insertposition As Integer = CutsTextBox.SelectionStart
        CutsTextBox.Text = CutsTextBox.Text.Insert(0, CutLength.ToString & "x" & _  
        CutWidth.ToString)
        CutsTextBox.SelectionStart = insertposition + inserttext.Length
    Next i
```

I even tried it with inserting the measurements into a ListBox.  Here is the code for that:

```
    Dim room As String = RoomsTextBox.Text
    Dim roomarray() As String = room.Split(vbCrLf)
    Dim Cuts(roomarray.Length - 1, 0) As String

    Dim CutLength As Integer
    Dim CutWidth As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    CutsTextBox.Select()

    Cuts(i, j) = (Val(roomarray(i).Split("x")(0))) & Val(roomarray(j).Split("x")(1))
    For i = 0 To Cuts.GetUpperBound(0)
        For j = 0 To Cuts.GetUpperBound(1)
            Cuts(i, j) = 0
        Next
        If Val(roomarray(i)) > 12 Then
            CutWidth = Val(roomarray(i)) - 12
            CutLength = Val(roomarray(j))

        Else
            CutWidth = Val(roomarray(i))
            CutLength = Val(roomarray(j))
        End If
        ListBox1.Items.Add(CutLength.ToString & "x" & CutWidth.ToString)
    Next i
```

Comment: So do you have your 5 new measurements, and you are just stuck on the adding them to a textbox on their own line, or are you stuck getting the measurements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out.

```
Dim dimensions As String() = txtInput.Text.Split(vbCrLf)
    Dim final As New List(Of String)

    For Each item In dimensions
        Dim lw As String() = item.Split("x")

        Dim length As String = lw(0)
        Dim width As Integer = CInt(lw(1))

        If width > 12 Then
            Dim new1 As String
            Dim new2 As String

            new1 = length & "x" & (width - 12).ToString
            new2 = length & "x12"

            final.Add(new1)
            final.Add(new2)

        Else
            final.Add(item)
        End If

    Next

    For Each item In final
        txtOutPut.Text += item & vbCrLf
    Next
```

Comment: Thanks Jack, that did exactly what I wanted.  I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Sorry just now marked it as the accepted answer, I'm new to this site and wasn't sure what that meant. Thanks again